# Convert Eclipse JUnit exported XML to HTML

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have a JUnit test suite that I'm running in eclipse as a plug-in test suite. When I run the tests the results show up in the JUnit view. I would like to get the results as an HTML file so that I can display them on an internal website.

The view menu has an Export option, but this produces XML not HTML. I've tried running the Ant JUnitReport task on the XML file but I get an error that its not the right format.

Is there an easy way to somehow export an HTML file from the JUnit view, or a way to convert the exported XML to HTML? I don't want to write a transformer myself if this is already a solved problem. (I know an easy way would be to take a screenshot of the JUnit view and post that as an image but I'd like a better solution if possible.)

Comment: Simply write an XSL-Transformation which gives you an XHTML file that can be displayed in a browser.

Comment: @Mike Kucera - this is the exactly the same issue that I am having - it seems the xml exported from eclipse is slightly different to that expected by the ant task - did you come up with any solution?

Comment: No sorry, I gave up on this some time ago.